# Can we manipulate the id assigned by jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, tabs, datepicker

I've a 3 jquery tabs which load the same jqgrid structure with different data.
I've a filter toolbar in the jqgrid. Couple of these fields are date fields so I've a date picker for user to select the date for filtering.

The date picker works fine in the grid in the first tab but breaks in other tabs. The selected  date is not populated in the search field.

This is how the tabs and grid look:
[image]

Here in the Pending tab, the datepicker works fine. But breaks in Approved and Additional Steps tab.

I noticed that the id assigned by jqgrid to a date search field is the same for the grids in all the three tabs. Is it possible that when I click on the second tab and grid, since the first tab's grid is in DOM, that breaks the date picker? Any ideas?

Update:

```
 { name: 'vpReportDate', index: 'vpReportDate',datefmt:"m/d/Y", sorttype:"date", width: 65, searchoptions:{dataInit:showDatePicker}, sortable:true },
```

Comment: jqGrid actually assigns an ID to the datepicker field? Wow, I would have expected it to use a class

Comment: Does your `VP Report` column have the same index/name (from the colModel) in all three of your grids?

Comment: @FastTrack Yes..I've updated the question with the respective code.

Answer (score 1):

I also use jQGrid with jQuery UI tabs and I've learned the hard way that each grid (since it can all be in the DOM at the same time) will need different column names/indexes.

You can change the `ID` of the search field by doing:

```
$("#tabs-tabID #gs_vpReportDate").attr("id", "#gs_vpReportDate_2");
```

Change `#tabs-tabID` to your jQuery UI Tab's ID.

However, this breaks the searching functionality since you are changing the default setup of jQGrid.

The real issue here is not the datepicker's ID, but all of the search field's IDs are going to be the same on each grid (since the names/indexes from the colModel are the same in each tab).

Although you may not like to hear this, the safest thing to do, which will save you many a headache in the future, is to change the names/indexes of each column for each grid. Since these grids will reside in the DOM simultaneously, you cannot repeat names/indexes in your colModel or situations like this will continue to haunt you.

What I would do (and have done in my own work) is just prepend something to the front of each **name** for **every column - not just the date columns** in your `colModel`. Like so:

Pending Grid:

```
name: 'pending_vpReportDate', index: 'vpReportDate'
```

Approved Grid:

```
name: 'approved_vpReportDate', index: 'vpReportDate'
```

Additional Steps Grid:

```
name: 'additional_vpReportDate', index: 'vpReportDate'
```

Comment: I can't agree with you more on the root cause of this issue. But then as you suggested to have different names for columns by prepending something to the column and index names, how will it work while retrieving the data from the server. It looks for the getter methods with the colnames right?

Comment: @tarares I completely agree! So here is what you do - just alter the `name` NOT the `index`. The `index` is what gets passed to the server - the name is for your input IDs and such... I just updated my answer

Comment: It didn't work..when I changed the name: 'vpReportDate' to name: 'pending_vpReportDate', no data gets displayed in the column.. :(..whereas in the response body I can see data against this column..looks like it matches with the name.